# Scala to parse string value sequence in custom format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I had a use case in spark-scala project where I need to query the states table and get the state codes from the table for each state. The state code values in parquet table are populated as follows:

```
state state_cd
GA    AGAHUI,AGAUTY,AGAERE
CA    BCAHRT,CCAYTU,CCARTE
```

Now in spark-sql query I need parse the state_cd values as

```
Where state = 'GA' and state_cd IN (${state_cd})
```

the place Holder state_cd has to be populated with below

```
${state_cd} = 'AGAHUI','AGAUTY','AGAERE'
```

Example how it will be inferred in Spark-SQL query:

```
Where state = 'GA' and state_cd IN ('AGAHUI','AGAUTY','AGAERE')
Where state = 'CA' and state_cd IN ('BCAHRT','CCAYTU','CCARTE')
```

Any Snippet of code/Suggestions in how to implement the logic for state_cd to get them transformed as
('AGAHUI','AGAUTY','AGAERE') from AGAHUI,AGAUTY,AGAERE using Scala

Answer (score 0):

How about, with the help of [split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#split(str:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,pattern:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) and [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#explode(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column):

```sql
WHERE state = 'GA'
  AND state_cd IN (SELECT explode(split(state_cd, ',')) as state_cd
                     FROM states
                    WHERE state = 'GA')
```